# python fabric run() sudo command without prompting for a password

Tags: python, fabric

I have this python fabric fabfile. I want to run the sudo command without prompting for a password. Would like to save the password in the file. Does Fabric3 no longer support the watchers option ? Is there any way I can put the password in the script?

```
from fabric.api import *
from invoke import Responder

env.user = "usera"
env.password = "password"

env.sudo_user = "usera"
env.password = "password"
env.sudo_prompt = "Password:"

sudopass = Responder (
        pattern=r'Password:',
        response=env.password + '\n'
        )

def itm_run ():
#    result = run("sudo systemctl restart S99itm", pty=True, watchers=[sudopass])
    result = run("sudo systemctl restart S99itm")
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

The watchers still work, otherwise check your pattern. You can also add `echo=True`.

For the password it is best to keep it in an env variable or such. so you can do `env.password = getenv('SOMEHOST_SOMEUSER_PASSWORD')`